# How can we determine GPS signal strength in iOS, apart from checking horizontal accuracy value

Tags: ios, iphone

I came across many answers in stack overflow like using horizontal accuracy parameter we can calculate GPS signal strength. But is there any other method to check the GPS strength in iOS.

Comment: Horizontal accuracy isn't really an indicator of GPS signal strength; it is a function of how many satellites are visible.  There are no indicators of GPS signal strength.  Also, in iOS14 the user can opt to provide non-precise location so your app may get a large value for horizontal accuracy even with a very good GPS signal.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for reply. Actually my requirement is to notify user whenever location accuracy is low, else wrong location will be captured for user. Is there any way to catch this

Comment: You can check the `horizontalAccurarcy` of the reported location, but the nature of GPS means that you can get an inaccurate location with a high accuracy. For example, signals bouncing off tall buildings in city centres can give you an inaccurate location with no indication of low accuracy.